# Amazon S3: `key` is the object being uploaded to bucket instead of the file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

Please check the below code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

public class UploadObjectSingleOperation {
    private static String bucketName     = "*******";
    private static String keyName        = "************";
    private static String uploadFileName = "C:/Users/Yohan/Desktop/asdasd.html";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(keyName, "**********"); 
        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
//            AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        try {
            System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
            File file = new File(uploadFileName);

            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                                     bucketName, keyName, file));

         } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                    "means your request made it " +
                    "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                    " for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                    "means the client encountered " +
                    "an internal error while trying to " +
                    "communicate with S3, " +
                    "such as not being able to access the network.");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

OK so above code I have is being used to upload files to Amazon S3 Bucket. My S3 bucket is in the nearest location to my client, `Asia Pacific - Mumbai`.

The above code works fine, however I noticed the following.

1. What is getting uploaded is always the `key` . The real file is not getting uploaded. Please check below image.

[image]

Why is this happening? When I upload file using the web interface of S3 it works totally fine.

Comment: I don't think your "answer" really the solution of your problem.
in s3, `keyName` is your **object name** , which including special prefix like slash or backslash. It has nothing to do with your AWS API Key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error. The code in my question is from Amazon tutorials - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

However I am sure it is incorrect or deprecated.

Pay attention to the below line

```
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file));
```

For this to work, instead of `keyName`, you have to pass the filename with extension. For an example `websitepage.html`.

Comment: The example code is correct. `private static String keyName` should have been set to the S3 object key -- which is what S3 calls `path/to-where-on-the-bucket-you-want-to-save/your/file/you/are/uploading.html`.  Not "key" as in "access key" but rather "key" as in "key/value store."  The path + name is the key, the file contents are the value.  See the terminology [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingObjects.html), for example.